# Distinct Initial Matrices

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

For a A * B matrix of all distinct numbers from 1 to A * B, we first sort each column and then concatenate all columns in increasing order of indices to form an array of size A * B. Columns are numbered in increasing order from left to right.

For example, if matrix is

[1 5 6]
[3 2 4]

We first sort all columns to get

[1 2 4]
[3 5 6]

Now, we concatenate columns in increasing order of indices to get an array

[1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6]

Given this final array, you have to count how many distinct initial matrices are possible. Return the required answer modulo 10^9+7.

Two matrices are distinct if:
- Either their dimensions are different.
- Or if any of the corresponding row in two matrices are different.

Example:

If input array is [1, 3, 2, 4], distinct initial matrices possible are:

[1 3 2 4]

============

[1 2]

[3 4]

=============

[1 4]

[3 2]

===========

[3 2]

[1 4]

===========

[3 4]

[1 2]

===========

that is, a total of 5 matrices.

Here is what is did:
I found the ways we can arrange values in every subarray of size(len/2).
So if an array is [1,2,3,4]
we have two subarrays [1,2]&[3,4].So the answer will be 2!*2!.Thing is we have to get the  unique rows as well.That's where my code failed.
Can you enlighten me in the right direction.
Here's my code;

```
 public int cntMatrix(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
    if(a.size()==1){
        return 1;
    }

    int n=a.size();
    int len=n/2;
    int i=0;
    long ans=1;
    if(n%2!=0){  //n is odd

        ans=fact(n); //factorial function

    }else{

    while(i<n){

        int x=i;
        int y=i+len;

        HashMap<Integer,Integer> map=new HashMap<>(); //frequency of each element in subarray[x..y]

        for(int m=i;m<y;m++){

            if(map.containsKey(a.get(m))){
                map.put(a.get(m),map.get(a.get(m))+1);
            }else{
                map.put(a.get(m),1);
            }
        }

        long p=fact(len);
        long q=1;
     for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> set:map.entrySet()){
            int key=set.getKey();
            int value=set.getValue();
            q*=fact(value);
        }

        ans*=p/q;   //ncr

        map.clear();
        i+=len;
    }
    }
    ans%=1000000007;
    return ((int)ans+1);
}
```

How to deal with unique rows

Asked on interviewbit.com

Comment: ok but neither computer nor anyone will know how you failed, unless you show your code

Comment: @I_Am_Innocent:Sorry. I am new here,didn't notice that code isn't there.Anyways happily edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that I noticed is that you check if the length is odd or not.

This is not right, if for example, the length is 9 you can arrange a 3x3 matrix that will suffice the conditions.

I think that you should try to "cut" the array into columns with the sizes 1 - n and for each size check if it can be an initial matrix.
The complexity of my algorithm is O(n^2), though I feel like there is a better one.

This is my python code -

```
class Solution:
# @param A : list of integers
# @return an integer
def cntMatrix(self, A):
    count = 0
    n = len(A)
    # i = number of rows
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            can_cut = True
            start = 0
            while start < len(A) and can_cut:
                prev = 0
                for j in range(start, start + i):
                    if prev > A[j]:
                        can_cut = False
                    prev = A[j]
                start += i

            if can_cut:
                count = (count + pow(math.factorial(i), n / i)) % (pow(10, 9) + 7)

    return count
```

I didn't check it on their site because the question page couldn't be found anymore, I saw it only on the ninja test.

After running -

```
s = Solution()
print(s.cntMatrix([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]))
```

We get - 217 = 3! * 3! * 3! + 1

Comment: Thanks for clarification @Daniel.Succesfully implemented. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
class Solution:
# @param A : list of integers
# @return an integer
def cntMatrix(self, A):
    self.factCache = {}
    bucket = 1
    buckets = []
    while bucket <= len(A):
        if len(A) % bucket == 0:
            buckets.append(bucket)
        bucket += 1
    valid_buckets = []
    for bucket in buckets:
        counter = 1
        invalid = False
        for i in range(1, len(A)):
            if counter == bucket:
                counter = 1
                continue
            if A[i] > A[i - 1]:
                counter += 1
            else:
                invalid = True
                break
        if not invalid:
            valid_buckets.append(bucket)
    combs = 0
    for bucket in valid_buckets:
        rows = bucket
        columns = int(len(A)/rows)
        combs += (self.fact(rows) ** columns)
    return combs % 1000000007
def fact(self, number):
    if number == 0 or number == 1:
        return 1
    fact = 1
    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        fact = fact * i
    return fact
```